# Azure Function to use connection from Azure Key Vault local development

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

We are developing the function locally and although we can use the ConfigurationBuilder().AddAzureKeyVault() in the startup to retrieve the Key Vault secrets, we are struggling to make the Queue trigger to get the connection string from the Key Vault. As can be seen below, the connection is currently retrieved from a AzureWebJobsStorage key present in the local.settings.json:

```
    [FunctionName("myFunction")]
    public async Task MyFunction([QueueTrigger("aQueue", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] Car myCar)
    {
        await getCarAsync(myCar.Name);
    }
```

local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=....",
```

Comment: You can also use `"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"` for local dev ?

Comment: @Thomas We are currently developing locally by using the AzureWebJobsStorage stored in the local.settings.json. But the goal is to migrate to Azure Key Vault so the developers don't need to store locally the connection string.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using dependency injection with either `FunctionsStartup` or `IWebJobsStartup` you can set the connection string from keyvault like this.

1. Set the `Connection` property on the `QueueTriggerAttribute` to an empty string eg

   ```
    [FunctionName("myFunction")]
    public async Task MyFunction([QueueTrigger("aQueue", Connection = "")] Car myCar)
    {
        await getCarAsync(myCar.Name);
    }
   ```

2. In your startup class use `PostConfigure<QueueAttribute>()` to set the connection string value, eg

   ```
   public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
   {
     public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
     {
        builder.Services.PostConfigure<QueueTriggerAttribute>(x =>
        {
            x.Connection = ReadQueueConnectionStringFromKeyvault();
        });
     }
   }
   ```

Another alternative to consider is [KeyVault references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references)

Comment: I followed your instructions. Particularly for QueueTriggerAttribute I had to add a "using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" despite I'm using functions. Also I had to leave the "AzureWebJobsStorage" property in the JSON with a dummy text, otherwise it complained about it being present. Finally, after running I'm getting this error message: https://i.imgur.com/Jsf4KS5.png

Comment: The queue trigger still is from this package https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage/Queues/QueueTriggerAttribute.cs

Have you verified that your start-up class is running?

Comment: Yes, I used a breakpoint there and also verified that the connection string was retrieved from Azure Key Vault properly.

Comment: Judging by the error message, you have an incorrect value for  AzureWebJobsStorage in your local.settings.json

Comment: Yes, I added a dummy text as we need to actually remove the connection string from that file and use the one coming from Azure Key Vault.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a documented issue with triggers, in some cases. (Taken from [this article](https://www.techwatching.dev/posts/azure-functions-custom-configuration).)

[image]